# How can I change my xbee setup for AP = 0 from API mode (AP = 1 or AP =2) by using digi module in python (AT mode or transparent mode)?

Tags: python, at-command, xbee

I am using XBee PRO S3B for wireless radio communication.

Currently I am configuring it by XCTU, however, sometimes I need to reset or re configure with non graphical interface.

Using digi module with python seemed good alternative to me. So here is my source code.

```
import digi
from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice
xbee0=XBeeDevice("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)
xbee0.open(force_settings=True)
xbee0.reset()
```

In this way I can reset my destination mac address. However, there is one critical drawback using this method. `xbee0.open()` is only supported by API mode, however, I am always using AT mode. So the command `force_settings=True` enables my AT mode to change into API mode, however, I am not sure how can I get back to AT mode. My device only works with AT mode so I need to go back to AT mode to do something. Is there any good solution for this?

Comment: Check the digi.xbee package for an "AT command" API and use it to set "AP" to 0 as a queued (instead of immediate) command and follow it up with a "WR" AT command to write that change to flash.  You could also see if the digi.xbee package exposes some methods for interacting with the module in AT mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice
from digi.xbee.models.mode import OperatingMode

xbee0=XBeeDevice("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)
xbee0.open(force_settings=True)
xbee0.reset()
xbee0.set_parameter(('AP'),bytearray([OperatingMode.AT_MODE.code]))
```